# confirm box using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how  to get confirmation before a export button is cliked.if yes then then export function has to be done if no it should not be done

Comment: see alternative jquery plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit/12357337#12357337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[confirm box?](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp)

```
if (confirm("Perform the export?"))
  performTheExport();
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are using asp.net. In webform applications, often we need a confirm dialog before doing postback.

```
//the page
<asp:button id="mybutton" runat="server" Text="Click to submit" />

//in code behind
mybutton.Click += (sender, args)=>
 {
     SubmitData();
 };

//if you need to confirm before submit, you can add:
mybutton.OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('are you sure?')) return;";
//another way
mybutton.Attributes["onclick"] = "if (!confirm('are you sure?')) return;";
```

If you want to use your 'own confirm box' instead of `confirm('are you sure?')`:

```
window.showMedalDialog('myConfirmPage.aspx')
```