# form confirm before submit

Tags: jquery

I am using a simple form and I want to allow the user to confirm before the form submits... I know this would be easy using jQuery, but I am a bit confused about code...

```
$(function() {
  $(".testform").submit(function() {
    $('.submitbtn').text('confirm');
  });
});
```

I know that the above code is not complete and I would like your help to finish it, so it would give an alert (using jQuery alert) that says 'Please confirm if everything is correct' and changes the text on the submit button to "confirm" instead of "submit". If the user clicks confirm again it would submit the form. I hope this makes sense. thanks.

Comment: Do you want an alert, or change the submit button's text?

Comment: There is another samples there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515632/548473

Answer (score 25, accepted):

sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z68VD/

**html**:

```
<form id="uguu" action="http://google.ca">
    <input type="submit" value="text 1" />
</form>
```

**jquery**:

```
$("#uguu").submit(function() {
    if ($("input[type='submit']").val() == "text 1") {
        alert("Please confirm if everything is correct");
        $("input[type='submit']").val("text 2");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks kei for your answer, i think this code will solve my probelm. 1 more thing my form is long so can i even send user at top of page after alert.

Answer (score 122):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var c = confirm("Click OK to continue?");
    return c; //you can just return c because it will be true or false
});
```

Comment: This is better than my solution.

Comment: Can you get the confirm() to work with the JQuery dialog-confirm?   Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17037698/3175526

Comment: Keep in mind that in new jQuery versions the preferred way of preventing the default action is `e.preventDefault()` instead of returning `false` in event handlers, since `return false` did too many things at once.

Comment: After seeing this, I tried `<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Sure?')">` and it worked lol. Why isn't this one of the solutions here? Does it not work with `method="get"` or on other browsers?

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I would do to get what you want :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testform").click(function(event) {
        if( !confirm('Are you sure that you want to submit the form') ) 
            event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

A slight explanation about how that code works,
When the user clicks the button then the confirm dialog is launched, in case the user selects no the default action which was to submit the form is not carried out.
Upon confirmation the control is passed to the browser which carries on with submitting the form.
We use the standard JavaScript confirm here.

Answer (score 13):

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="save" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        if( !confirm('Are you sure that you want to submit the form') ){
            event.preventDefault();
        } 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply...

```
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
   return confirm("Click OK to continue?");
  });
```

or

```
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
   var status = confirm("Click OK to continue?");
   if(status == false){
   return false;
   }
   else{
   return true; 
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<body> 
    <form method="post">
        name<input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Save?')">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer.  I don't know why it's so low.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [easy-confirm-plugin](https://github.com/wiggin/jQuery-Easy-Confirm-Dialog-plugin) i did it:

```
(function($) {
    $.postconfirm = {};
    $.postconfirm.locales = {};
    $.postconfirm.locales.ptBR = {
        title: 'Esta certo disto?',
        text: 'Esta certo que quer realmente ?',
        button: ['Cancela', 'Confirma'],
        closeText: 'fecha'
    };
    $.fn.postconfirm = function(options) {
        var options = jQuery.extend({
            eventType: 'click',
            icon: 'help'
        }, options);
        var locale = jQuery.extend({}, $.postconfirm.locales.ptBR, options.locale);
        var type = options.eventType;
        return this.each(function() {
            var target = this;
            var $target = jQuery(target);
            var getDlgDv = function() {
                var dlger = (options.dialog === undefined || typeof(options.dialog) != 'object');
                var dlgdv = $('<div class="dialog confirm">' + locale.text + '</div>');         
                return dlger ? dlgdv : options.dialog;          
            }           
            var dialog = getDlgDv();
            var handler = function(event) {
                    $(dialog).dialog('open');
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
            };
            var init = function() 
            {
                $target.bind(type, handler); 
            };
            var buttons = {};
            buttons[locale.button[0]] = function() { $(dialog).dialog("close"); };
            buttons[locale.button[1]] = function() {
                $(dialog).dialog("close");
                alert('1');
                $target.unbind(type, handler);
                $target.click();
                $target.attr("disabled", true);
            };            
            $(dialog).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                width: 'auto',
                minHeight: 120,
                maxHeight: 200,
                buttons: buttons,
                title: locale.title,
                closeText: locale.closeText,
                modal: true
            });
            init();
        });
        var _attr = $.fn.attr;
        $.fn.attr = function(attr, value) {
            var returned = _attr.apply(this, arguments);
            if (attr == 'title' && returned === undefined) 
            {
                returned = '';
            }
            return returned;
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

you only need call in this way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mybuttonselector").postconfirm({ locale: {
                        title: 'title',
                        text: 'message',
                        button: ['bt_0', 'bt_1'],
                        closeText: 'X'
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.testform').submit(function() {
  if ($(this).data('first-submit')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    $(this).find('.submitbtn').val('Confirm').data('first-submit', true);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a habit I've gotten into. It's an easy way to store information associated with a particular DOM element. In this case, the form. This means you could easily replace `.testform` with any any other selector returning a form and the code would work independently for each form.

Answer (score 0):

Single line:

```
<form action="url" method="POST" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();if(confirm('Save this?'){this.submit();};">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var r = confirm('Want to delete ?'); 

if (r == true) { 
    $('#admin-category-destroy').submit(); 
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything that isn't already covered here.