# Jquery UI dialog as confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

```
  function Globally() {
    $("#dialogid").dialog({ width: 300, modal: true, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () { return true; $(this).dialog('close'); },
            "Cancel": function () { return false; $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }
    });
  }

  function test()
  {
    if(Globally())
      alert("Ok");
    else
      alert("Cancel");
  }
```

I am trying to make a confirmation dialog and I want it to placed in a function (in this case Globally()) because I am using confirmation dialog in so many different function, but this is not working , the control returns from the `Globally()` function without getting `true or false` value. I want it to stop there until user press `Ok or Cancel`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can check this fiddle, check the confirm dialog http://jsfiddle.net/mostthingsweb/6Rumh/39/

Comment: There is a easy to use plugin to do it here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit – fd748s7d8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit%20%E2%80%93%20fd748s7d8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use built in confirm function if you want to run code like that:

```
var question = confirm("Proceed?")
if (question){
   // continue
 } else {
   // stop
 }
```

That is because only confirm when used prevent whole javascript execution and allows you to pick one answer or the other (Ok, Cancel).

Dialogs like jQuery dialog can not stop script execution so even if you use

```
if(Globally())
  alert("Ok");
else
  alert("Cancel");
```

It'll just execute Globally() function and continue right after it - not waiting for a user answer.

If you really want to use jq dialog then add callback functions to your buttons.

```
"Ok": function () { callbackFunctionTrue(); },
"Cancel": function () { callbackFunctionFalse(); }
```

And ditch if/else statement() in test function.

Answer (score 0):

That;s not how it works

Just do

```
    "Ok": function () { alert('OK'); $(this).dialog('close'); },
    "Cancel": function () { alert('Not ok'); $(this).dialog('close'); }
```

or

```
    "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog('close'); test(1) },
    "Cancel": function () {$(this).dialog('close'); test(0) }
```

with

```
function test(ok){
  alert(ok?"Ok":"Cancel");
}
```