# How to stop script when using jQuery Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm sure this has been asked here many times. The [latest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10663079/2063610) one I saw was on *Dec. 2012*. But I would like to ask if someone's got a **fix/better workaround** for this problem.

I'm using `jQueryUI Dialog` and I would like to ask if it is possible to **stop the script execution** when the dialog pops up and the user haven't selected an answer yet. Just like the javascript `confirm()` does.

Here's what I have so far:

**jQuery**

```
$("#GlobalDialogBox").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
        "Yes": function () { 
            callbackFunctionTrue();
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
         },
        "No": function () { 
            callbackFunctionFalse();
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
         }
      }
    });

   alert("This should fire after answering the dialog box."); //but this fires as soon as the dialog pops up.. :(
```

The `alert` is a common part of the script that fires after answering the dialog box regardless of the answer. On my fix, I just inserted the `alert` in `callbackFunctionTrue()` and `callbackFunctionFlase()` and it does the job.

But what if I don't want to do that? How would I stop the script when the dialog pops up so that I can freely add my codes below the `dialog` script? Does anybody have a better solution? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance! :]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924588/1166285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dialog is being closed it triggers close event. You can do that by adding event listener to your dialog:

```
$("#GlobalDialogBox").on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) {
      alert("something");
});
```

or in more consistent way:

```
$("#GlobalDialogBox").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () { 
            callbackFunctionTrue();
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
         },
        "No": function () { 
            callbackFunctionFalse();
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
         }
    },
    close: function(event, ui){
       alert("something");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really pause script execution arbitrarily. Callback functions are your best solution in this case, so below your buttons options on the dialog add a close event handler and put your alert and any other code you want to execute after the dialog closes in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dialog_confirm(){
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    //autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        dialog_confirm_callback(true);
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        dialog_confirm_callback(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
function dialog_confirm_callback(value) {
  if (value) {
    alert("Confirmed");
  } else {
    alert("Rejected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to do that. What you have implemented is the same as I implemented when in the same situation and it worked just fine. Launch the dialog in its own JavaScript function, and launch your yes/no functions based on which element gets clicked. No alert box required.

Answer (score -3):

you can use the **return** to stop the function.

Comment: he wnats to pause it not stop it