# How to detect confirm() choice?

Tags: javascript

I have this jquery code that generates a yes/no dialog box when the user click a button.

```
$('#btnFinalize').click(function()
{
   confirm("Are you sure?");            
});
```

But how can I detect if the user click yes/no?

Comment: if this is all your code, all you need is to add a `return`: `.click(function() { return confirm("Are you sure?") })`

Comment: see plugin and example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit/12357337#12357337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm); it will be `true` or `false`:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?! DAMN sure?')) {
    // yes
}
else {
    // no
}
```

Comment: that's great. thanks ! I've been searching about this dialog boxes and all the results i can get are very complicated. :)

Answer (score 5):

[**`confirm()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) returns `true` if the user clicked "yes" ; and `false` if he clicked "no".

So, basically, you could use something like this :

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    // clicked yes
}
else {
    // clicked no
}
```

Comment: Thanks thanks! if I can give a check on you two I will :) TY BTW :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#btnFinalize').click(function()
{
   var reply = confirm("Are you sure?");         

    if (reply)
    {
        // your OK
    }
    else
    {
        // Your Cancel
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`confirm()` will return true or false, depending on the answer. So you can do something like:

```
$('#btnFinalize').click(function()
{
   var finalizeAnswer = confirm("Are you sure?");
   if(finalizeAnswer) {
       // do something if said yes
   } else {
       // do something if said no
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'Confirm()' returns 'true' if you press 'yes', and 'false' for 'no'.