# Implement jQuery confirmation modal in a form submit?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery modal confirmation like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:190,
      width: 330,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        No: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });

  <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Genalytics">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure want to unshare?</p>
</div>
```

I have a input button in a form like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Unshare" name="unshare" />
```

I want to popup dialog box when user clicks on the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the submit event in the form where the submit button is.

```js
$(function() {
    var submit = false;
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:190,
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 330,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          submit = true;
        },
        No: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $('form').submit(function() {
        if (!submit) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did that but the text is displayed with the dialog box like this on the bottom of the page "Are you sure want to unshare?" And When I click on the button no popup is displayed.

Comment: @user2032220 you can create dialog outside of event with `autoOpen: false` and use `dialog('open');` inside the event.

Comment: Please update your answer and I will mark your answer best answer. Thank you

Comment: I have button inside a div :
      <div class="btn" id="unShare">
          <input type="submit" value="Unshare" name="unshare" disabled onclick="return shareConfirm()" />
          <input type="hidden" id="pageNum" value="{{ page }}" />
        </div>
        </form>
Does it matter?

Comment: @user2032220 onclick event will not work on submit you need to use submit function on a form. or onsubmit attribute if you need to put a function inside html.

Comment: Can I just put onclick=functioName() in the submit input form. I did that for a Javascript alert and it worked.

Comment: @user2032220 but it will not prevent submiting of a form. but the alert will block the submit because everything stops when it's show up. Only `return false` (or `preventDefault`) in submit form will prevent submiting a form.

Comment: Alright got it. Like you said, the Unshare button should display the dialog box and if the user presses Yes jquery should submit the form. If the user presses no, form should not be submitted. How can I do that?

Comment: Your solution above, doesn't show the the line at last first and whenever I click on the unshare button the modal is not shown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31572/discussion-between-jcubic-and-user2032220)

Answer (score 2):

I have created Model popup by own no third party plugin.

Could you please try given link.

```
<input type="button" id="btnShowSimple" value="Simple Dialog" />
<input type="button" id="btnShowModal" value="Modal Dialog" />
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/937kH/)

Hope it likes you.

Comment: Good job.  I like the example.