# How to confirm a request by clicking a button

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a laravel app whereby if user send a request you have to confirm by clicking a button. Which is the best method to implement that. Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Like a popup? If so I would recommend using a modal, once you click on say **"Confirm"**, the modal would then popout

Answer (score 1):

If its a form request you can just add to the Button-Element a 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" like so:

```
<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> Send Request </button>
```

a Popup Window will ask you for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using JavaScript.  You can easily achieve this with JQuery.

Have a look at this, I think this is what you need: [form confirm before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit)